# Pandas is asking me to make a column a string, but I cannot

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, types

I'm trying to convert a pandas column to a string in order to use `str.extract()`.

When I run `print(data.dtypes)`, this is what I see:

```
:Address Line 1:         object
:City:                   object
Address Line 2:          object
Case Initiation Date:    object
Case Number:             object
Case Status:             object
Defendants               object
Demand Amount:           object
Motion Status            object
Zip:                     object
6                        object
dtype: object
```

I'm trying to split the `data['Motion Status']` variable using a regular expression, but am running into roadblocks. First, here's a quick look at `data['Motion Status']`:

```
0    b'01/31/202008:30155'
1    b'02/03/202008:30155'
2    b'02/03/202008:30155'
3    b'02/04/202008:30155'
4    b'02/04/202008:30155'
Name: Motion Status, dtype: object
```

You'll note that it's of the format dd/mm/yyyy + hh:mm + 3-digit number. This is the code I have been using to try and parse out the date from the time (i'll do the '155' after i've got it working):

`data['Motion Status (date)'] = data['Motion Status'].str.extract('\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}', expand=True)`

When I run it, it returns the error `TypeError: Cannot use .str.extract with values of inferred dtype 'bytes'.` I've tried four different solutions, but none of them have worked (returning the same error message as above when I re-run the `str.extract` line):

`data['Motion Status'] = data['Motion Status'].astype('|S')`

`data['Motion Status'] = data['Motion Status'].astype('str')`

`data['Motion Status'] = data['Motion Status'].astype(str)`

`data.astype(str)['Motion Status'].map(lambda x:  type(x))`

Can anyone help me out here? I'm really not wedded to converting this variable to a string. I just want to be able to parse out the date, time, and the '155' at the end (it's not always a '155' by the way - only in the first 20 rows or so).

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update:**

I can now run this line of code `data['Motion Status (date)'], data['Time'], data['Other'] = data['Motion Status'].str.extract('(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', expand=True)` and it executes without an error. I honestly don't know what i've done to make this run... However, I now run into a slightly different issue where the code creates three new variables but they are filled with zeros, ones, or twos in all rows (and not the parts of the data['Motion Status'] string I was hoping to get. E.g.

```
   Motion Status (date)  Time  Other
0                     0     1      2
1                     0     1      2
2                     0     1      2
3                     0     1      2
4                     0     1      2
```

So i'm not exactly back to square one, but I still haven't managed to be able parse out the different parts of the string.

Comment: give `str.decode` a try:   `data['Motion Status'] = data['Motion Status'].str.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: This works to convert the variable, but i still get the same error when I try and run the `str.extract()` line. 

I ran these two lines of code: `data['Motion Status'] = data['Motion Status'].str.decode('UTF-8')` and `data['Motion Status'] = data['Motion Status'].astype('str')` but when I run `data['Motion Status'].str.extract('\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}', expand=True)` I get the error `TypeError: Cannot use .str.extract with values of inferred dtype 'bytes'.` even though when I run `print(data.dtypes)` it indicates that `Motion Status` is type `|S32`

Answer (score 1):

You have bytes in the column. `decode` it first using `str.decode` method:

```
s

#0    b'02/03/202008:30155'
#1    b'02/03/202008:30155'
#2    b'02/04/202008:30155'
#3    b'02/04/202008:30155'
#dtype: object

s.str.decode('UTF-8').str.extract('(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', expand=True)

#    0   1     2
#0  02  03  2020
#1  02  03  2020
#2  02  04  2020
#3  02  04  2020
```

Comment: This has resulted in three columns filled with NaN values. This is the exact code I ran `data['Motion Status'].str.decode('UTF-8').str.extract('(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', expand=True)`, and this was the output:
```
      0    1    2
0   NaN  NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN
...
```

Comment: Can you tell which version of python and pandas are you using?

Comment: pandas : 0.25.3 and python : 3.7.4.final.0 I got these by running `pd.show_versions()`

Comment: For some reason, when i'm trying this line of code again (after removing everything from memory and bringing it in again), i'm getting a slightly different error: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: It's likely your column are not of string type. Could try `astype(str).str.decode('utf-8')`. You need to check what are the actual data types in the column first.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I already tried that. I can decode and turn all variables into float64s and then when I try and run astype(str) it turns them all back into 'objects' which I cannot use string functions on

Comment: Not sure what data you have. Can you create a snapshot of your data frame using `df.to_json()` and paste here ?

Comment: Sure! And thanks. I've changed some personal data, and i've had to give only a snippet of the variables (otherwise i exceed the character limit): `'{"Case Number:":{"0":"","1":" ESX LT-000001-20","2":" ESX LT-000011-19","3":" ESX LT-000012-19","4":" ESX LT-000013-19"},"Defendants":{"0":"","1":"Full  Name","2":"Full  Name","3":"Full  Name","4":"Full Name"},":City:":{"0":"","1":" Townsville","2":" Townsville","3":" Townsville","4":" Townsville"},"Motion Status":{"0":"","1":"01\\/27\\/202008:30155","2":"02\\/04\\/201908:30155","3":"02\\/04\\/201908:30155","4":"02\\/04\\/201908:30155"}}'`

Comment: I have a suspicion that your data is not consistent in the `Motion Status` column. What if you try `df['Motion Status'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('UTF-8'))`? Does it complain as well ?

Comment: I get a different error now, on the decode function: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. 

No problem by the way. I really appreciate your thoughts/suggestions but also appreciate this might not be easy to figure out without seeing the data. If you have other ideas, i'm all ears and can try them out - would understand if you want to throw in the towel though!

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what i've done but somehow i've had a breakthrough. I can now run this code and creates three variables filled all with '0', '1', or '2' (still not the bits of the Motion Status string I want to split up but closer! `data['Motion Status (date)'], data['Time'], data['Other'] = data['Motion Status'].str.extract('(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', expand=True)`